# Compactly generated complete lattice is Heyting Algebra

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $L$ be a lattice. $a\in L$ is said to be *compact* if whenever $a\leq \bigvee A$ for some $A\subseteq L$, then there is some finite subset $B\subseteq A$ such that $a\leq \bigvee B$. A lattice is *compactly generated* if each $a\in L$ is the supremum of a set of compact elements.

Now let $L$ be a distributive lattice, which is complete and compactly generated. I am asked to show this lattice $L$ must be a Heyting algebra.

We know that a complete distributive lattice is a Heyting algebra if and only if the infinite distributivity law holds, that is:
$$a\wedge\bigvee_{i\in I}b_i = \bigvee_{i\in I} (a\wedge b_i)$$

I have tried fiddling around with the definitions, that is, rewriting all $a,b_i$ as suprema of compact elements, but without any result yet. How can I see this claim to be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete compactly generated lattices are usually called *algebraic*. So we need to prove that every algebraic distributive lattice satisfies the infinite distributive law. The inequality from right to left is trivial.

Let $x = a \wedge \bigvee_{i \in I} b_i$. Since $L$ is algebraic we have $x = \bigvee C$ for some set $C$ of compact elements of $L$. For each $c \in C$ we have $c \leqslant \bigvee C = x = a \wedge \bigvee_{i \in I} b_i$ and hence $c \leq a$ and $c \leq \bigvee_{i \in I} b_i$. By the compactness of $c$ we have $c \leq b_{i_1} \vee \dots \vee b_{i_n}$ for some $i_1, \dots i_n \in I$. Hence $$c \leq a \wedge (b_{i_1} \vee \dots \vee b_{i_n}) = (a \wedge b_{i_1}) \vee \dots \vee (a \wedge b_{i_n}) \leq \bigvee_{i \in I} (a \wedge b_i).$$

Finally, we have
$$a \wedge \bigvee_{i \in I} b_i = x = \bigvee C \leq \bigvee_{i \in I} (a \wedge b_i),$$
where the last inequality holds since for each $c \in C$ we have $c \leq  \bigvee_{i \in I} (a \wedge b_i)$.

Note that for arbitrary (not necessarily distributive) algebraic lattice $L$ this law holds in the weaker form, namely, when $\{b_i \mid i \in I\}$ is a directed subset of $L$. See the related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621561/algebraic-lattices-and-distributivity-over-joins-of-upward-directed-sets/1622453#1622453).